# after background subtraction how to detect segmented object?

Tags: visual-c++, opencv, image-processing

I am trying for object detection using opencv 2.4.2. Here is the code for my moving foreground subtraction. Now I want to detect moving object in original frame and draw bounding box around it.
can anybody please help me? how to do that?

```
   #include "stdafx.h"
   #include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
   #include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
   #include "opencv2/contrib/contrib.hpp"
   #include "conio.h"

   #include "time.h"
   #include "opencv/cvaux.hpp"
   #include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
  #include "opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp"

  using namespace std;
 using namespace cv;
   int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {  


  int key = 0; 

    CvSize imgSize;
    CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromFile( "S:\\offline object detection   database\\TwoEnterShop2cor.MPG" );

         IplImage* frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );
         imgSize = cvGetSize(frame);

        IplImage* grayImage = cvCreateImage( imgSize, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
        IplImage* currframe = cvCreateImage(imgSize,IPL_DEPTH_8U,3);
         IplImage* destframe = cvCreateImage(imgSize,IPL_DEPTH_8U,3);
    if ( !capture ) 

  {  
    fprintf( stderr, "Cannot open AVI!\n" );  
    return 1;  
  }


    int fps = ( int )cvGetCaptureProperty( capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FPS );

   cvNamedWindow( "dest", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );

   while( key != 'y' )
  {
  frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );

   currframe = cvCloneImage( frame );// copy frame to current
   frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );// grab frame
   cvAbsDiff(frame,currframe,destframe);

cvCvtColor(destframe,grayImage,CV_RGB2GRAY);
cvSmooth(grayImage,grayImage,CV_MEDIAN,3,3,0);
   cvAdaptiveThreshold(grayImage,grayImage,230,CV_THRESH_BINARY,CV_ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,3,5);

     cvDilate(grayImage, grayImage, 0,1);
 cvErode(grayImage,grayImage, 0, 0);
  if(key==27 )break;
  cvShowImage( "fram",currframe);
  cvShowImage( "dest",grayImage);
   key = cvWaitKey( 100 );
   }  
  cvDestroyWindow( "dest" );
  cvReleaseCapture( &capture );
  return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You should use C++ versions of these functions, not those `cv*`.

Answer (score 0):

Frame difference is the simplest method of background subtraction, but it's very sensitive to threshold you used and may not get good results.The better way is to estimate background model, compare each frame and background model to determine moving objects.

You can find further information from following links:
[Background subtraction in OpenCV(C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7765877/background-subtraction-in-opencvc)
[Background Subtraction with OpenCV 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13100605/background-subtraction-with-opencv-2)